# revert back to android 2.1 in samsung galaxy 5 aka europa from cyanogenmod 7 gingerbread 2.3

Tags: samsung

I have installed android 2.3 gingerbread in my galaxy 5 europa GT-I5500 following [this post](http://igyaan.in/2011/10/independence-special-upgrade-samsung-galaxy-5-android-2-3-4-gingerbread/14857/)
Now want to go back to 2.1, any dictation how to do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something wrong with Cyanogenmod?

What you want is the stock version of android Samsung put on the phone, there is no revert as it was deleted when you put cyanogen. As you dont seem to have a copy I would go to Samsung support site or you will have to trust another source on the net and download it there. This would be another great community resource for your phone http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1156

Comment: If he had a nandroid backup of the previous rom, that would work too right?

Comment: Yes many things are not working properly. 1. Bluetooth 2. When radio on bluetooth becomes on. 3. EDGE disconnect now and then 4. Consequent video file download in opera mini replaces the previous file etc etc. Thank you for the community link. But can you please dictate me what I need to do specifically to get 2.1 in my device?

Comment: The problems you have described here sound fixable, cyanogen is a high quality and widely used rom with many advantages over the stock roms samsung makes, try downloading the latest one for your model and installing it again. If your problems are still there address them one by one, otherwise like i said you will have to research where to get the stock rom again most likely there is a samsung support that can help you.

Comment: Yess!! Back to 2.2 and its working fine.. here is the solution link http://www.madteam.co/2011/10/11/flash-samsung-stock-rom-over-cm-guide/#comment-1985 . And thanks for your help it gave me hope. Even lost the swype which i like very much in CM. Still I am noob in the CM world. I will learn and try step by step. For now back to safety.

Comment: @Power-Inside: I am also wondering!!

Comment: @newcomer Good for you I hope this fixes your problems, since you probably still have clockwork recovery on there you should look into nandroid backup, it creates a file on the sd card that you can backup and restore from if you come into problems again.